# Expose modules from module to module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, fs

I've node application which need to get path to folder and read all the files from there.

**e.g**

```
moduleA
 -server.js 
 -controller 
  --load.js
```

in the load.js I've method(`loadFolderFiles`) which should get path to file
path and load all the files from it.

Now from module B I need to require moduleA and add path to folder to read files

Application B structured like following:

```
 appB
   -src
    --files
      ---fileA.js
      ---fileB.js
   -server.js
```

Inside the appB server.js I'm doing the following(to load moduleA)

```
var moduleA = require('moduleA')
moduleA.loadFolderFiles('/appB/src/files')

moduleA.start();
```

Now moduleA will start to load the files for the provided path(I want to use `glob` for it).

**My question are**:

1. I publish moduleA as npm module and my question how should I expose 
   the API of **moduleA.loadFolderFiles**(recommended way)?

2.How should I provide the path for it(relative /absolute) and read the files
from module appB?

This is the "moduleA" in npm (for testing)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/samplenodeapp

This is the code for moduleB to load moduleA

```
 var sample = require('samplenodeapp');
    sample.start();
```

The code which I expose module a is like following

```
var express = require('express');
var loadModule = require('./controller/load')
var app = express();
function start (){
    app.listen(3001, function () {
        console.log("App is listenting on port 3000");
    })
}
module.exports = {
    start:start, 
    loadModule:loadModule
};
```

As you can see I exposed method from the controller/load like following (to provide the api for loadFolderFiles, is it OK?

Comment: Is call to `loadFolderFiles` required before calling `start`?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев - yes the loadFolderFiles should be called before :) , now I got it...

Comment: If I want to use moduleA, could I do it like so: `var moduleA = require('moduleA'); moduleA.start()`?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев - yes I use this exactly (see the code at the end of my post) and this is working but not sure if it right...since I need to require the ('./controller/load') to export it that appB can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting load folder is required, I would suggest to move it either to `start` arguments or to module settings.

```
var moduleA = require('moduleA')({ loadFolder: '/path/to/folder' });

// or
var moduleA = require('moduleA');

moduleA.start({ loadFolder: '/path/to/folder' });
```

If you chose to move it to the module settings, you should export a function from that module.

```
var createLoader = require('./controller/load');

module.exports = function (params) {
   // params === { loadFolder: '/path/to/folder' }

   var loadModule = createLoader(params.loadFolder);

   return {
       start: start,
       loadModule: loadModule
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks :) so I've two questions 1. if I want to load in the future more then one folder how you suggest to do it ?(From Api prespective) 2. how its recommended to read the files for given path?

Comment: I must've misunderstood your question. What does `loadFolderFiles` do, setting a folder for upload? Or maybe attaching additional middlewares to express app?

Comment: loadFolderFiles are getting path for a folder (from wrapper module/app like appB)and load it maybe with fs or glob...(not related to middleware)

Comment: Then your version seems perfect to me. I would stick to absolute paths though, they're more reliable.

Comment: Ok thank you 1+, can you just provide example how should I implement this inside moduleA (your first suggestion ) var moduleA = require('moduleA')({ loadFolder: '/path/to/folder' });

Comment: Sure, updated my answer. By the way, it's exactly how `express` works.

Comment: Thanks now I was able to test it (in debug) but the problem is when I enter to the module export code with params there is noting with the inside module(I mean with the controller/load.js) how its **recommended** to call it from it?

Comment: as you can see in my post I use the following module.exports = {
    start:start, 
    loadModule:loadModule
};  which loadModule need to refer to the load.js file ,so in your example how its suggested to do it?

Comment: You want to pass the params to the inner module, right? You can achieve this by the same trick: `load` module should export wrapper function, that takes configuration params and returns `loadModules`.

Comment: Thank you last question :) since we use the shorthand like your suggestion var moduleA = require('moduleA')({ loadFolder: '/path/to/folder' });   , and since the start is a function I must return it like following return {
       start: start(),
       loadModule: loadModule
   }  , the start function exported like this **start()** , is there another way to do this from outside, that I should only do start:start ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110997/discussion-between---and-nina-s).